# I am just developing .net code?

Tags: c#

```
code:

using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Configuration;

public partial class Registration : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (IsPostBack)
        {
            SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["RegistrationConnectionString"].ConnectionString);
            conn.Open();
            String checkuser = "select count(*) from [UserData] where 'UserName'='"+ TextBox1UN.Text +"'";
            SqlCommand comm = new SqlCommand(checkuser,conn);
             int temp = Convert.ToInt32(comm.ExecuteScalar().ToString());
            if(temp==1)
            {
                Response.Write("user allready exists");

            }

         conn.Close();

        }

    }

    protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
            {
            SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["RegistrationConnectionString"].ConnectionString);
            conn.Open();
            String InserQuery = "insert into [UserData](UserName,Email,Password,Country)values(@Uname,@email,@pass,@country)";
            SqlCommand comm = new SqlCommand(InserQuery,conn);
            comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Uname", TextBox1UN.Text);
            comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@email", TextBox2EI);
            comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@pass", TextBox3PW.Text);
            comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@country", DropDownList1cont.SelectedItem.ToString());
            comm.ExecuteNonQuery();
            Response.Write("Registration is succesful");
            Response.Write("Administrator.aspx");

            conn.Close();
        }
        catch (SqlException ex)
        {
            Response.Write("Error:"+ex.ToString());
        }
    }

    protected void TextBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    protected void DropDownList1cont_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }
}
```

Error:

- No mapping exists from object type System.Web.UI.WebControls.TextBox
  to a known managed provider native type.

Description:

Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.

Exception Details: System.ArgumentException: No mapping exists from object type System.Web.UI.WebControls.TextBox to a known managed provider native type.

Source Error:

```
Line 43:             comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@pass", TextBox3PW.Text);
Line 44:             comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@country", DropDownList1cont.SelectedItem.ToString());
Line 45:             comm.ExecuteNonQuery();
Line 46:             Response.Write("Registration is succesful");
Line 47:             Response.Write("Administrator.aspx");


 Source File:  c:\Users\user6\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\WebSites\loginPage\Registration.aspx.cs    Line:  45 

Stack Trace: 



[ArgumentException: No mapping exists from object type System.Web.UI.WebControls.TextBox to a known managed provider native type.]
   System.Data.SqlClient.MetaType.GetMetaTypeFromValue(Type dataType, Object value, Boolean inferLen, Boolean streamAllowed) +2328239
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlParameter.GetMetaTypeOnly() +190
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlParameter.Validate(Int32 index, Boolean isCommandProc) +16
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.BuildParamList(TdsParser parser, SqlParameterCollection parameters, Boolean includeReturnValue) +201
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.BuildExecuteSql(CommandBehavior behavior, String commandText, SqlParameterCollection parameters, _SqlRPC& rpc) +241
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReaderTds(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, Boolean async, Int32 timeout, Task& task, Boolean asyncWrite, SqlDataReader ds, Boolean describeParameterEncryptionRequest) +2026
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReader(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, String method, TaskCompletionSource`1 completion, Int32 timeout, Task& task, Boolean asyncWrite) +375
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.InternalExecuteNonQuery(TaskCompletionSource`1 completion, String methodName, Boolean sendToPipe, Int32 timeout, Boolean asyncWrite) +337
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery() +192
   Registration.Button1_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e) in c:\Users\user6\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\WebSites\loginPage\Registration.aspx.cs:45
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.OnClick(EventArgs e) +9692746
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.RaisePostBackEvent(String eventArgument) +108
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.System.Web.UI.IPostBackEventHandler.RaisePostBackEvent(String eventArgument) +12
   System.Web.UI.Page.RaisePostBackEvent(IPostBackEventHandler sourceControl, String eventArgument) +15
   System.Web.UI.Page.RaisePostBackEvent(NameValueCollection postData) +35
   System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) +3562
```

Comment: In the parameter for the email you have forgot to use the Text property.

Answer (score 1):

In the line `comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@email", TextBox2EI);` it should be `TextBox2EI.Text`.

Also, in the line `comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@country", DropDownList1cont.SelectedItem.ToString());` I think you should be passing the Text or the Value - it depends of what you want - of the SelectedItem and not the SelectedItem it self.